# How to filter multiple users in htop?

Tags: htop

TL;DR:  Is there any way to filter two users processes at the same time in htop?

I'm trying to get a list of processes of several users in htop. Code below seems not to work as second --user flag overrides the first one.

```
htop --user=user1 --user=user2
```

Similarly,

```
--user=user1,user2
```

also didn't work, although it works for PIDs with

```
--pid=PID1,PID2
```

command.

I tried from htop itself with F4 filtering, however I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

htop author here! No, it is currently not possible, as of htop 2.2.0, but I'll keep that in mind as a feature request!

Answer (score 1):

to show multiple processes it is possible to use top. Here an example of two processes:

```
top -p $(echo `pgrep -d "," processname1`,`pgrep -d "," processname2`)
```

Comment: Welcome to [su] ... the question asks to filter on user - how is your answer able to do that?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1173403)

Answer (score 1):

As of htop v3.2 this is now possible with the pipe (`|`) character

`htop --filter="ruby|puma|postgres"`